# Python Unusual error with multiline code in IDLE Shell

Tags: python

I was testing some code on IDLE for Python which I haven't used in a while and stumbled on an unusual error.

I was attempting to run this simple code:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
print('Done')
```

I recall that the shell works on a line by line basis, so here is what I did first:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
        print(i)
    print('Done')
```

This resulted in a indent error, shown by the picture below:

[image: Indent error from IDLE]

I tried another way, as it might be that the next statement needed to be at the start perhaps, like this:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
        print(i)
print('Done')
```

But this gave a syntax error, oddly:

[image: Second error, a syntax error from IDLE]

This is quite odd to me the way IDLE works.

Take note:
I am actually testing a much more complex program and didn't want to create a small Python file for a short test. After all, isn't IDLE's shell used for short tests anyways?

Why is multi-line coding causing this issue?

Comment: It is hard to say much without knowing exactly what you typed (including white space) but IDLE is famously quirky. In any event, there is no sane reason to type multiline code directly in the IDLE shell. Anything beyond a couple of lines should be in a code window (or in a better IDE).

Comment: @JohnColeman I agree, next time I will reconsider using IDLE, but come to think of it the example I used is only three lines. The final print is unecessary in this case, but useful in my 'larger project'. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: For interactive purposes, use the Python interactive (just type in `python` on the command line) or IPython.

Comment: @Tomothy32 I appreciate the advice to avoid IDLE, but I would like to know what I happen to be doing wrong in this particular case which looks simple.

Comment: IDLE doesn't like multiple lines unless their all part of the same statement (e.g. `if`, `for`, etc.), so you'll either have to run your `for` statement, then enter the `print` statement, or you'll have to put them both inside another statement. I would recommend that you put them both into a `def` statement, making a function that does both, then you can execute the function to see it actually run.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54155721/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hit <kbd>Return</kbd> once or twice after the `print(i)`, until you get the `>>>` prompt again. Then you can type the `print('Done')`. The Python interpreter is waiting for you to tell it that you're done working inside that `for`. And you do that by hitting <kbd>Return</kbd>.

(You'll see, though, that the `for` loop is executed right away.)